# Cómo poner bien el string

Tags: javascript, nodejs

el ejercicio dice "Escribí la función escribirCartelito, que tome como parámetros un título, un nombre y un apellido y devuelva un único string como resultado. Por ejemplo:"
`//  Si ejecutamos la función con éstos datos... escribirCartelito("Dra.", "Ana", "Pérez"); //  ...la misma nos  devuelve "Dra. Ana Pérez",`

```js
//  Si ejecutamos la función con éstos datos...
escribirCartelito("Dra.", "Ana", "Pérez");
//  ...la misma nos  devuelve "Dra. Ana Pérez",
```

yo intente hacerlo con el siguiente

```js
function escribirCartelito (doctora, ana, perez){
    return "doctora" + "ana" + "perez"}
```

No sabría qué estoy haciendo mal, me gustaría que me guiaran cómo escribir bien el código.

Comment: Quita el `;` que hay despues de los paréntesis.

Comment: Tienes mal la sintaxis de la función, como bien te dice, te sobra el `;`

Comment: No se entiende por qué editaste la pregunta pues, básicamente, no se entiende cuál es el problema que tienes ahora. Por qué dices que lo estás haciendo mal? QUé error sale? Hazlo como con el error del punto y coma, no pongas a adivinar a la gente (que tampoco viene a hacer todo por ti)

Answer (score 2):

```js
/*
1. Los argumentos de la función deben ser genéricos, en este caso titulo en lugar de `doctora`, nombre en lugar de `ana`... etc
2. Lo que la función hace es concatenar esos argumentos, se prefiere el uso de "string literal" (``) para tener una sintaxis más limpia
3. Luego se llama la función con los valores correspondientes en sus argumentos.
4. La función solo retorna un texto, para poder verlo hay que ponerlo dentro un console.log
*/

function escribirCartelito (titulo, nombre, apellido){
    return `${titulo} ${nombre} ${apellido}`
}

console.log(escribirCartelito('Dra.', 'Ana', 'Perez'))
```

Answer (score 0):

En el intento que hiciste tu funcion recibe tres parametros pero nunca los usas, solamente devolves una cadena pero los parametros no los usas. Despues esos parametros deberian tener un nombre mas adecuado como "titulo" "nombre" y "apellido", ya que no tenes que imprimir solamente "Dra Ana Perez", podes usar esa misma funcion para imprimir por ej: "Licenciado Jorge Rodriguez".

```
function escribirCartelito (titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return `${titulo} ${nombre} ${apellido}` // uso de plantillas literales, muy utiles
}

console.log(escribirCartelito("Lic.","Jorge","Rodriguez"))
```

entonces la funcion recibe 3 cadenas y las devuelve en una sola, con un espacio de por medio, y la imprimimos en consola.